# Query XML Node and nothing is returned

Tags: xml, vbscript

Source file contains, for example (note the multiple `<?xml` lines):

```
08/29/2018
08:47:21
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ExtendedData><Header><Date>08/29/18</Date>.. other data</ExtendedData>
08/29/2018
08:50:53
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ExtendedData><Header><Date>08/29/18</Date>.. other data</ExtendedData>
```

Need to query the xml with VBScript and we do not have the option of PowerShell (I know it would be better).

I used the following TechNet article to get the start of basis of the script I am using:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.10.heyscriptingguy.aspx

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim FL,oFSO,objFolder,colFiles,objFile,FLPath,FLName,f1,line,xmlDoc,colNodes,objNode,strDate

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("H:\Documents\Journal_Files")
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile In colFiles
    FLPath = objFile.Path
    FLName = objFile.Name
    If InStr(FLName, ".jrn") > 0 Then
        'WScript.Echo FLPath
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmlDoc.Async = "False"
        xmlDoc.Load(FLPath)
        Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//ExtendedData/Header/Date")
        For Each objNode in colNodes
            Wscript.Echo objNode.Text 
        Next
    end if
next
```

The issue is that there is nothing returned for date.

Comment: Your source data is not valid XML. You need to extract the nested XML documents before you can process them with an XML parser.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - XML Paser, you could be right.  I think I had done a similar operation using grep and awk when working request/response flows using Apache Tomcat.